# Blazor WASM : error while ReadFromJsonAsync <List<Object>> Post crud

Tags: c#, json, httprequest, blazor, crud

I have this [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGIcJ.png)

> The Json value could not be converted to
> System.Collections.Genereic.List
> 1[Blazor_fresh_project.Shared.Feedback]. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 |
> BytePositionInLine: 1.

when I'm trying to CreateObj in this method :

```
public async Task<List<Feedback>> CreateFeedback(Feedback feedback)
        {
             var resulte = await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync($"api/feedback",feedback);
            string content = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(resulte);
            Console.WriteLine("Here is THE CONTENT " +content);
             var   feedbacks = await resulte.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<List<Feedback>>();
            return feedbacks;
        }
```

This error happen at line :

```
 var   feedbacks = await resulte.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<List<Feedback>>();
```

The console write :
[Console debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9RCy.png)
Do you have any suggestions or tips for debugging this kind of error?

Edit : [api/feedback request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZg9I.png)

```
namespace Blazor_fresh_project.Server.Controllers
{

    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class FeedbackController : ControllerBase
    {
        List<Feedback> Feedbacks = new List<Feedback> {
           new Feedback{Id=1,Name="arthur",Description="I think this is great",DateOfPost=DateTime.Now,Power=10},
           new Feedback{Id=2,Name="Mario",Description=" coming soon",DateOfPost=DateTime.Now,Power=8},
           new Feedback{Id=3,Name="Chipolo",Description="I think this is great",DateOfPost=DateTime.Now,Power=17},
           new Feedback{Id=4,Name="Coco",Description=" coming soon",DateOfPost=DateTime.Now,Power=12},
           new Feedback{Id=5,Name="Marguerite",Description="I think this is great",DateOfPost=DateTime.Now,Power=6},
           new Feedback{Id=6,Name="Carine",Description=" coming soon",DateOfPost=DateTime.Now,Power=4}
            };
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetFeedbacks()
        {
            return Ok(Feedbacks);
        }

        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetSingleFeedback(int id)
        {
            var feedback = Feedbacks.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Id == id);
            if (feedback == null)
                return NotFound("this feedback wasn't found");
            
            return Ok(feedback);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateFeedback(Feedback feedback)
        {
            feedback.Id = Feedbacks.Max(h => h.Id + 1);
            Feedbacks.Add(feedback);
            return Ok(feedback);
        }
    }
}


namespace Blazor_fresh_project.Client.Services
{
    public class FeedbackService : IFeedbackService
    {
        private HttpClient _httpClient;
        public FeedbackService(HttpClient httpClient)
        {
            _httpClient = httpClient;
        }
        [Authorize]
        public async Task<List<Feedback>> GetFeedbacks()
        {
          return await _httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Feedback>>("api/feedback");

        }

        public async Task<Feedback> GetFeedback(int id)
        {
            return await _httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<Feedback>($"api/feedback/{id}");
        }
        [Authorize]
        public async Task<List<Feedback>> CreateFeedback(Feedback feedback)
        {
             var resulte = await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync($"api/feedback",feedback);
            string content = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(resulte);
            Console.WriteLine("Here is THE CONTENT " +content);
             var   feedbacks = await resulte.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<List<Feedback>>();
            return  feedbacks;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The first line is where the problem is. You are making a post to 'api/feedback'. Are you sure it's meant to return a list of feedbacks?

Comment: thank you for your reply @Qudus
Yes I do, the answer of request "https://localhost:44392/api/feedback"
return all my "Feedback",(I added a screen of this)

Comment: The string in the Console screenshot does not match that of the request. One has `[]`, the other not.  You are not getting the same API results.

Comment: Alright @HenkHolterman, but I can still use the getALL method in this way?
Can you clarify this for me? I added another screen to the post method.
Thank you for help.

Comment: The rule on this site is not to post (too many) screenshots of code or errors. Add them as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'Console' screenshot shows us a payload of a single Feedback item, the request-in-a-browser shows a list of Feedbacks.

Your code is doing a POST, the browser does a GET. Apparently you have an endpoint with different return types for GET and POST.

<strike>Post the (relevant) code of your controller if you need more help.</strike>

OK, so indeed you have. You can change your controller or what looks more logical, your client:

```
    public async Task<Feedback> CreateFeedback(Feedback feedback)
    {
      var resulte = await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync($"api/feedback",feedback);
      var feedback = await resulte.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<Feedback>();
      return feedback;
    }
```

and adapt the calling code accordingly.

Comment: Okay ! I finally got this, this is clear now.
Thank you for your time!